# Hibernate - 1:N - The parent is duplicated upon saving the child

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, one-to-many, cascade

[GitHub repo if needed, Maven web project (pom.xml), SQL script under resources directory.](https://github.com/Jouo/hibernate_problem)

I'm aware this is my fault, the problem is I haven't been able to fix it in the entire day, its likely something simple and over my head, also please ignore the relations regarding the table names and columns, it's a sample project to show the problem.

---

**Expected:**

Store the new child along its parent relation (the child has a column for it), without storing the parent again.

---

**Error:**

***CascadeType.ALL*** causes the parent to duplicate, but attempting to remove it to use the other types throws: *java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_id' cannot be null*

**Column 'user_id'** is the name of the column in the child table that stores the parent relation.

---

*I will skip some annotations among other things so this doesn't become a wall of code*

---

**User entity**

```
private Long id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Username> usernameList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Username entity**

```
private Long id;
private String username;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

Again, using anything but **CascadeType.All** throws an error for some reason

---

**UsernameDAO** (*this is the method being used to store the child, username, which duplicates the parent, user*)

```
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
session.save(username);
```

**UsernameService**

```
usernameDAO.save(username);
```

Comment: Please log the Username and User instances before save operation and post the result.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I will do so right now, I should make it a habit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the way you are assignment the object User in the object Username is incorrect. If you are doing something like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.set(... // set your attributes

Username username = new Username();
username.set(user);
```

Now if you save the `username`, hibernate will create a entry in the database for `user` because the way you have created `user` is by using the `new` keyword and this will make a new entry in the db.

If you don't want to create a new entry for the `user`, then you will have to load the entity from the database, so you should add a new method in your service class `User` which will return you a user given a user id.

e.g:

```
User user = userService.getUser(10);

Username username = new Username();
username.set(user);
```

Now when you will save `username`, this will not create a new entry in the table `User`. This is the way hibernate works. We have to load the entity, then do our operation on it and save it. The `new` keyword will create a new entry even if the id of the entity (primary key in db) is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it's actually already loading them from the database :( I'm passing an array of User to the model, then I bind that array to an Spring's <form:select>

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if it's wrong to answer one's own question, so I just remove this.

The problem was in the front-end, I had the following in my Spring Form:

```
<form:select path="user" items="${listUsers}" />
```

When it should of been

```
<form:select path="user.id" items="${listUsers}" itemValue="id"/>
```

---

1) If **itemValue** is not specified Spring will take the value from **toString**.

2) Use the **id** field (binded entity) as the **itemValue** and the relationship field **id** as the **path**

3) You don't necessarily have to remove **ClassType.PERSIST** in order to avoid duplicates, as long as your entities are binded by their unique identifier (like the **id**), otherwise hibernate will see it as a new entry.